# permutation with local variables bugs

Tags: java

I'm testing the permutation codes from Stanford c++ lecture. Why do I introduce a bug if i use my local variables? I tried debugging it but I still don't understand it.

```
public class JavaApplication9 {

    public static void permutate(String so_far, String rest  ){

        if (rest.equals("")){
            System.out.println(so_far);

        } else {

            for (int i = 0; i < rest.length(); i++){

            so_far = so_far + rest.charAt(i);
            rest =  rest.substring(0,i) + rest.substring(i+1);
            permutate(so_far, rest);

            }

        }

    }


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        permutate("", "ab");
    }

}
```

Output should be:  ab, ba.

Currently getting just:   ab

Comment: expected output, observed output?

Comment: You don't return `so_far` or `rest`, so they lose scope when `permutate` finishes. What did you think would happen?

Comment: i thought it would get all the permutations back. I sitll don't understand why i never get B-A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By overwriting the values of `rest` and `so_far` inside the for loop, you lose the original version.  Here's what the calls to `permutate` looklike if we unroll the loop.

```
so_far = "a"
rest = "b"
```

next time through loop:

```
so_far = "ab"
rest = ""
```

Because the values of `so_far` and `rest` changed inside the for loop, when i=1, the original values passed in to `permutate` can't be used only the new modified versions are.

However, if you use different variable names inside your for loop the unrolled loop looks like this:

```
tmp_so_far = "a"
tmp_rest = "b"

tmp_so_far = "b"
tmp_rest = "a"
```

Next time through loop:

```
tmp_so_far = "ab"
tmp_rest = ""

tmp_so_far = "ba"
tmp_rest = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Because when you update rest to the new rest, you overwrite the old string. You're modifying it in the loop so when you do rest.length() it's the new length as you've lost the old string.

Example:
when the passed in rest == "ab", in the first iteration rest.length() == 2. but in the loop you updated rest to "b". so when you got back from permute() your rest is now "b" and the length is 1, so when you increment i, it becomes 1 and you fall out of the loop.

Changing to newRest solves the problem as you still have the old rest passed into the method.